# how can i get the front or top element of a vector queue?

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list, queue

I didn't put the full code because it was very long and i only need help with the small portion which is the **** area. i can't seem to use front() or top() to get the top element of the queue. I tried making top() function List keep getting error : 1) class List has no memeber named 'top' which means i don't have a function top in List, when i make it it says 2) no match for 'operator=' in printer_cpu[i] = SList::top() with T=PCB]()'

```
template <class T>
class node{
public:
T data;
node *next;
};

template <class T>
class List{

node<T> *head;
node<T> *tail;

public:

List()
{
    head = tail = NULL;
}

bool isEmpty()
{
    if(head == NULL) return true;
    else             return false;
}

void enqueue(T new_data){
    node<T> *temp = new node<T>;
    temp->data = new_data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(isEmpty()){
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
    else{
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
}
void dequeue(){
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        cout << "The list is already empty" << endl;
    }

    node<T>* temp;
    if(head == tail){
        temp->data=head->data;
        delete head;
        head = tail = NULL;
    }
    else{
        temp->data = head->data;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}
node<T> top()  // need help here ****
{ 
     return head;
}

void display(){
    node<T> *current = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        cout << current->data << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}


};


struct PCB
{
    int ProcessID;
    int ProcessorSize;
    int priority;
    string name;
};
typedef List<PCB> printing;
typedef List<PCB> disk;

void gen(vector<printing> &printer_queue,string printer_name[], int printers)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < printers; i++)
    {
        int num = i+1;
        ostringstream convert;
        convert << num;
        printer_name[i] = "p" + convert.str();
        printer_queue.push_back(printing());
    }
int main()
{
        int numOfPrinter = 5;
        string interrupt;
        cin >> interrupt;
        PCB cpu;
        PCB printer_cpu[numOfPrinter];
        string printer_name[numOfPrinter];
        vector<printing> PQ;
        gen(PQ,printer_name,numOfPrinter);
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfPrinter; i++)
        {
              if(interrupt == printer_name[i])
              {
                   cout << "Enter a name for this printer file: " << endl;
                   cin >> cpu.name;
                   PQ[i].enqueue(cpu);
                   printer_cpu[i] = PQ[i].top(); //need help here ****
              }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing an asterisk, because you need to return of type pointer, because that's what head is.
You should have

```
node<T> * top() 
{
  ...
}
```

You also need to overload the = operator, because you are trying to compare type PCB with type node *.

Comment: doesn't template class the whole thing make it type T? and it gave me an error declaration of class T

Comment: You're right -- I didn't see you had it all in one class

Comment: Perhaps you forgot an asterisk? node<T> * top()?

Comment: Oh, try node::Node<T> * top()

Comment: nope :/ here the error im getting no match for 'operator=' in printer_cpu[i] = a long list of something

Comment: feel like im missing a operator for it?

Comment: You must be comparing two arbitrary types. If you are using types that you made with the = operator, then you have to overload it.

Comment: Yes, thats it. You are trying to compare type PCB with type node. You need an overload for that

Comment: ahhh okay thanks lemme see if i can come up with an overload for it

Comment: hmm can you help me i can't seem to get the overload

Answer (score 0):

Well, I compile your code successfully after correcting some mistakes.

I didn't meet `class List has no memeber named 'top'` problem.

Then your `top()` function returns the value of `head`, so you should change it to: `node<T>* top()` because `head` is a pointer to `node<T>`.

And the reason you got `no match for 'operator='` error is that `printer_cpu[i]`'s type is `PCB` while `PQ[i].top()`'s type should be `node<T>*`

I have also found that the code you post lacks a `}` just before `int main()`.

Comment: hmmm maybe that the problem my type has to be in PCB :/

Comment: is there a way to fix no match for 'operator='?

Comment: hey u think u can help me with the operator= ? i tried writing it several time and it won't get it to work. it won't accept another variable or vector

Comment: bool operator = (const PCB &c)
    {
        ProcessID = c.ProcessID;
    }

Comment: `printer_cpu[i] = PQ[i].top();`  The type of `printer_cpu[i]` is `PCB` but the type of `PQ[i].top()` is `node<PCB>*`, so you got `operation= errror`. You can change it to `printer_cpu[i] = PQ[i].top()->data`

Comment: yea i did that and it crashes xD some1 pointed that out just a few minutes ago

Comment: you can add some print statements just after `printer_cpu[i] = PQ[i].top()->data` to find whether this statement causes crash or not

Comment: i test it out when i comment it it crashes right at printer_cpu[i] i even added if(!PQ[i].empty()) cout << something whenever it hits printer_cpu[i] crashes

Comment: sorry, I have no idea what happened. I compiled the code you post successfully after some changes. And it also run without crash. Maybe some other places in your code lead to crash. And here is my code after some changes: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23592413/). Hope it helps.

Comment: yea whenever it putting the top file into the PCB printer_cpu it is crashing ;/

Comment: ur's didnt crash mine crashed T_T like no tomorrow :S

Comment: if i put it in a while(true) will that affect it?

Comment: changing to while loop makes no sense. You can add `if (PQ[i].top() == null)` before using `PQ[i].top()->data` and test it again.

Comment: If you still can't solve the problem, you'd better show your full code to someone around you and ask for help. From the code you post here, I can not find further information. Good luck. ^ ^

Comment: i already posted i up and deleted it cause everybody kept telling me it had something to do with my linked list T_T thx

Comment: i'm gonna try to figure another way to make a vectors of queues or something that generate queues